# Get the coordinates of the largest submatrix

Tags: algorithm, submatrix

I have the largest submatrix `m1 x n1` of a submatrix `m x n`. I found how the maximum submatrix sum but I would like to know how to find the coordinates at r1c1 (first row and first column of that submatrix) and r2c2 (last row and last column of that submatrix).

So far I have pre-processed matrix that stores its sums at each element, as in:

```
SUM[i, j] = SUM[i−1, j] + SUM[i, j−1] − SUM[i−1, i−1] + MATRIX[i, j]
```

I have found that for any given r1, c1, r2, c2:

```
SUMS = SUM[r2,c2] - SUM[r1-1,c2] - SUM[r2,s1-1] + SUM[r1-1,c2-1]
```

How should I approach this problem if I want to get the output that could tell me the coordinates of this submatrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can brute force all possible `r1` and `r2`, then you can again brute force all possible `c1` and `c2` for this `r1, r2` pair and calculate the sum of this submatrix by your `SUM` array, it's straight forward, but not efficient.

### Time complexity O(m<sup>2</sup>n<sup>2</sup>)

---

Let's try to improve it. You can know the sum of `r1` to `r2` for each column in `O(1)` time by doing some pre-processing. In this way, we turn a 2D largest submatrix problem into a 1D [Maximum Subarray Problem](https://medium.com/@rsinghal757/kadanes-algorithm-dynamic-programming-how-and-why-does-it-work-3fd8849ed73d) which can help us find `c1` and `c2` for this `r1, r2` pair in `O(n)` time.

### Time complexity O(mn<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: i have already found the max sum but what i am looking for is the indices of the max submatrix

Comment: @Hemal You can store the indices for the max submatrix while doing this algorithm

Comment: Do you get what I mean? You can do something like: If the current submatrix is larger than the one found before, then store the sum of this submatrix and current `r1, r2, c1, c2`

Comment: then what could be the representation of the current indices?

Comment: @Hemal the max submatrix found so far. And if we find a better (larger) submatrix later, then just update the indices and the sum.